# HTML with CSS to PDF using a php library

Tags: php, css, pdf, tcpdf

I've tried out FPDF and TCPDF in the past... I've also checked out options of running chrome in headless mode to generate PDFs... I'm wondering if anyone has any experience of the best way to convert something like this to PDF. I ask, because it uses more complex CSS than my previous PDF projects. Is there anything that will convert the following well?

Edited:
Thanks to the pointer to mPDF... I've successfully generated a PDF using the code below. 
However, part of the CSS should include a small triangle, which makes the box look like a speech bubble... that doesn't come out because BEFORE and AFTER are not supported.

Does anyone know how to replicate the effect below without using before and after? I'm applying it to a `<p>` tag.

```
<style>
.triangle-border1 {
  position:relative;
  padding:15px;
  margin:1em 0 1em;
  border:5px solid #F7827B;
  color:#333;
  background:#fff;
  /* css3 */
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
}


.triangle-border1:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:40px; /* controls horizontal position */
  border-width:20px 20px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#F7827B transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}


.triangle-border1:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-13px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
  left:47px; /* value = (:before left) + (:before border-left) - (:after border-left) */
  border-width:13px 13px 0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:#fff transparent;
  /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
  display:block;
  width:0;
}

</style>
```

The desired output is this:
[image]

but I can't make use of before and after as I'm outputting to PDF via mPDF which doesn't support it.

Comment: I use [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf). It has a lot of features. Take a look. You can add stylesheets too so the CSS doesn't have to be inline

Answer (score 0):

Please, consider [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org), which I've succesfully used on centos and windows, allows you to print a page visible only to a logged-in user or something of the kind. It can manipulated from your php project.

And [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf), a very easy to use php library.

`wkhtmltopdf` is no longer maintained and has been archived in january 2023 (see https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm stuck with PHP 5.5.11, so am using mPDF 6... Most of the CSS is working fine, but I've edited the main post to include the output and desired output... Close, but not quite there.

Comment: I don't think mPDF supports pseudo css... before and after won't work.

Comment: I liked mpdf more than fpdf and tcpdf. But I did write special styling for a number of documents. The mpdf docs contain explanation about specific css properties support. The wkhtmltopdf uses a different approach, it allows you to create basically a screenshot of your page.